# Passing Dynamic Date Part to Date_Add in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to pass a dynamic string to the date part that comes after the integer in the date_add function?

I.e.

```
date_add('2023-01-01', interval 7 {dynamic_date_part})
```

where {dynamic_date_part} could be 'day', 'week', 'month' etc?

I tried this but it rejects anything that gets put there as just "unexpected"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to add the dynamic date part:

```
select date_add(dte, interval n {dynamic_date_part}) as date
from (select current_date as dte, 1 as n union all
      SELECT CURRENT_DATE, 2)
```

As `1` and `2` in

```
from (select current_date as dte, 1 as n union all
      SELECT CURRENT_DATE, 2)
```

represent the day/week/month of interval.

Here is the query and output:
[image]